# Duda al realizar una consulta SQL para un buscador avanzado

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tardes.

Estoy realizando para mis practicas, junto a un compañero, una web y una base de datos. Entre las funciones de la web, se encuentra un buscador avanzado, con varias opciones.

Mi problema surge en hacer una consulta concreta entre 3 tablas, las cuales son (resumidas):

Tabla "molecula":
Id, Nombre, Peso molecular, etc(..)

Tabla "actividad biologica":
Id, Nombre

Tabla intermedia:
idMolecula, idActividad_Biologica

Una molecula puede tener varias actividades y viceversa. El problema aparece cuando quiero saber que moleculas tienen la actividad 1 y la actividad 5, por ejemplo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Nombrefrom molecula as m join actividad_biologica_has_molecula as abm on abm.molecula_idMolecula=m.idMolecula join actividad_biologica as ab on ab.idActividad_Biologica=abm.Actividad_Biologica_idActividad_Biologica where ab.Nombre="Lorem" and ab.Nombre="Ipsum"
```

El problema es que he revisado manualmente que la molecula tenga ambas propiedades, pero no me lo muestra. En cambio, si lo hago por separado no hay problema.

Answer (score 1):

Calculo que lo que estás buscando es esto:

```
select m.Nombre
from molecula as m 
join actividad_biologica_has_molecula as abm 
    on abm.molecula_idMolecula=m.idMolecula 
where 
    abm.Actividad_Biologica_idActividad_Biologica in (1,5)
group by m.Nombre
having count(1) > 2
```

Entiendo que el join a actividad_biologica no es necesario para esta consulta

Comment: Pues ha funcionado ^^ Llevaba un rato dandole vueltas al asunto :)

Comment: @CarlosGargallo Si esta respuesta ha resuelto tu problema puedes agradecerle al autor marcándola como acertada a la izquierda de la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: No tengo la reputacion minima requerida para que mi voto cuente :(